# 2010 trek madone 4.7 vs newer but lower spec

Tags: road-bike

I recently asked this question when I wasn't signed in but I didn't really give enough detail despite getting some good answers so I am posing the question again.
Should I buy a trek madone 4.7 from 2010 I believe when it cost
2100 pounds back in 2010 and it has a fully carbon frame and shimano ultegra groupset or should I purchase a newer bike like a boardman team carbon which is only a few years old but much lower spec with tiagra components and heavier, will will older bike be a let down even in very good condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There have been some significant improvements over the last 10 years, so I'd definitely look to get something new.
2010 bikes were not bad at all, but there have been a number of incremental improvements over the years that add up to an all round better package.

- Most bikes in 2010 did not have internal cable routing for improved looks and aerodynamics
- New bikes will generally have larger/stiffer bottom bracket areas for more efficient power transfer
- In 2010 not much was being done in the way of aero design.  Most new bikes will probably have more aerodynamic tube shapes
- In 2010 most manufacturers were still trying to make frames as stiff and light as possible.  A new bike will likely have some design features to promote vertical compliance and a more comfortable ride.
- A 2010 bike is unlikely to have much tyre clearance.  A new bike will likely be able to take wider more comfortable tyres.

A small disadvantage to a new bike is that between wider tyres, disk brakes and more aerodynamic tube profiles, they have generally become a little heavier than older models.

Comment: A 2010 Ultegra Madone would have been close to if not the top-of-the line Trek road racing frame so there's a good chance it'll have internal cables, stiffer/larger bottom bracket, and maybe even some aerodynamic improvements over a generic frame.  But yeah, it'll be stiff and won't take larger tires, errr, tyres.  ;-)

Comment: I think the biggest improvements since 2010 are hydraulic disc brakes, wider tyres and 11 speed shifters.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the internal cables and larger BB areas didn't start become mainstream until a few years later.  Trek still have the 2010 Madone on their archive and it shows external routing and the typical skinny round tubes: https://archive.trekbikes.com/ca/en/2010/trek/madone47#/ca/en/2010/trek/madone47/details

Comment: A bit more investigation using the archive - internal cable routing had reached the top of the line 6 series Madone, but not the lower 4/5 series frames

Comment: @AndyP Well dang.  I bought a Neuvation F100 back in 2009 that had aero features and internal cable routing, and the frame was nothing more than an off-the-shelf Kinesis frame.  I figured that if an off-the-shelf stock mass-market frame had those features in 2009, a higher-end Trek racing frame from a year later would too.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

I think it very much depends on what you compare the 2010 Madone to. If you compare it to a new entry-level road bike with aluminium frame, 10 speed Shimano Tiagra groupset with rim brakes and cheap-ish wheelset I’d definitely pick the Madone. Assuming it’s in good condition.

Both will have 10 speed shifting but the Madone will be lighter, probably more comfortable and higher quality. It would be different if you compare it to a more expensive modern bike which might have hydraulic brakes, 11 speed shifting, more comfortable (carbon) frame, better aerodynamics etc.

There is nothing inherently bad about old bikes. It’s easy to get replacement parts for a bike like the 10 year old Madone. Age itself can cause some rubbers and plastics to degrade, but that only means you might have to replace the brake pads and tyres (assuming they are still original).

Comment: This is my thinking. As a general caveat for future readers, there are occasionally generational changes in bike technology that make upgrading to new parts difficult or even impossible, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Road bike tech has improved fairly little. Slap some new, high quality tires on that Madone (if not already equipped with such) and it will ride just fine.

Comment: Not true for Madone, according to reviews IsoSpeed noticeably improves comfort.